# how to write if condition in rules tag in jquery

Tags: jquery

any body can help me im suffering for writing if condition in jquery rules tag..
see the below tag..

```
    $("#submit-btn-id").on("click",function(){
        var formValid = getValidator("#userRegistration", {
            rules : {
                firstname : "required",
                lastname: "required",
                password:"required",
                gender:"required",
                email:{
                    required:true,
                    email:true
                },
                phone:"required",
                //select:"required",
                select:{
                    required : true,
                    selectNone: true
                    },
  if(("#selectid option:selected").val() == '3'){
                        dateOfJoining:"required",
                        idCardNumber:"required",
}
    else if(("#selectid option:selected").val() == '3'){
                        code:"required",
                        creditLimit:"required",
                        depositAmont:"required",
                        idProofNumber:"required",
                        identyProof:"required",
                        "panNumber":{panNumber:true},
    }
   else  if(("#selectid option:selected").val() == '4'){
                        AgentApicreditLimit:"required",
                        AgentApidepositAmont:"required",
                        AgentApinoOfIp:"required",
    }
                        "AgentApipanNumber":{AgentApipanNumber:true}
            }
    });
```

Comment: What is the problem of your code?

Comment: Would it not suffice to simply move the `if` statement (and all associated `else` statements) before you call `getValidator`?

Comment: You forgot to put the $ jquery into your if condition.

Answer (score 0):

From JQuery you can add a function to do your logic as the attribute value.

**Approach 1:** 
Add all validation attribute, some will have true value some will false value as depends on your logic.

Here's an example from [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

```
$(".selector").validate({
  rules: {
    contact: {
      required: true,
      email: {
        //Note here how they placed some logic into the function
        depends: function(element) {
        return $("#contactform_email:checked")
      }
     }
    }
   }
  });
```

To relate to your code, you can do something like this:

```
...
   code: function (){
                           //your logic here. 
                           //DON'T FORGET THE $ 
                          return $("#selectid option:selected").val()==3                          
                       },

   creditLimit: function(){return $("#selectid option:selected").val() == '3'},
    ...

   dateOfJoining: = function ()
   {
      //your logic goes here 
      if(("#selectid option:selected").val() == '3')
      {
      return "required"; //this will be the value of  dateOfJoining
      }
   }
```

---

**Approach 2:**

As suggested by Archer in the comments. You can build your `getValidator` object before calling `getValidator`. In addition,  `getValidator` requires an object as a second parameter. It doesn't really matter where you declare that object. Therefore, you can prepare that object before you call `getValidator`

Example:

```
$("#submit-btn-id").on("click",function(){
var valObject = {};//this will be the rules object

    if(("#selectid option:selected").val() == '3'){
                       valObject ["dateOfJoining"] = "required" ;//we add attributes based on the logic
                       valObject ["idCardNumber"] = "required" ;// we add more 

attributes           
//here add more attributes as if they satisfy the condition. 
         }

//Add more conditions, more constrain as above to add more required attributes. 
   var rules = {"rules" : valObject } ; //assign all attributes that you've already defined to the rules object. 
//And then call your validation
var formValid = getValidator("#userRegistration", rules );
};
```

Both ways works fine. You just need to pick the easier approach for you.

Comment: many more thanks for posting this answer.but we want to add in rules tag according my logic and 2,3,4 are the select list value according to user selected it will select..

Comment: @Dusmant you will get the same exact result. Where you add the rule has no effect as long at the end all required attributes are defined. Have you tried approach 1 or approach 2?